# mysql remove very last character

Tags: mysql, string

you would think this is answered somewhere but I cant find the exact answer. 
I need to remove the very last character in a string, it can be any character and the string can be any length.

example 992899d needs to be 992899

Comment: No, it is not. The answer there would just display the stripped value and not actually delete the last character and store it back to the database.

Answer (score 21):

Any solution using **SUBSTRING** would only display the field's content by deleting the last character. *It would not actually update the content of the column.* If that is what you want(i.e. using it with **SELECT**) then **SUBSTRING** is enough.

**But, if you want to actually *update the value of the column*, you can try the following:**

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET <column_name> = CONCAT(LEFT(<column_name>, CHAR_LENGTH(<column_name>) -1), '')
WHERE <condition>;
```

This would replace the last character with nothing, hence the last character would be deleted.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Concatenating the empty string is unnecessary; the following query would do the same thing:   
UPDATE <table_name>
SET <column_name> = LEFT(<column_name>, CHAR_LENGTH(<column_name>) -1)
WHERE <condition>;

Answer (score 10):

You are probably looking for `SUBSTRING(column, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(column)-1)`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring for reference.

Comment: for anybody that runs unit testing through SQLite, the expression compatible with both MySQL and SQLite is `SUBSTR(column, 1, LENGTH(column)-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRIM([{BOTH | LEADING | TRAILING} [remstr] FROM ] str)` because you already know what section of the string you want to be removed.

Here is a table with dates and a given quantity that I pulled from my database:

```
select date_format(date, '%m/%d %I:%i%p') as Date ...
Date        | QTY
-------------------
3/5 11:30AM | 46
3/5 11:30PM | 23
3/6 11:30AM | 12
...
```

Using Trim:

```
select trim(trailing 'M' from date_format(date, '%m/%d %I:%i%p')) as Date ...
Date        | QTY
-------------------
3/5 11:30A  | 46
3/5 11:30P  | 23
3/6 11:30P  | 12
...
```

Credit to https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php for helping me understand trim